# Makefile always compiling certain files

Tags: c++, makefile

I've created a Makefile for my Project Euler solutions directory, and I'm having some issues with it continually recompiling some solutions, regardless of a lack of changes. Also, the `*.o` files created for these recompilations are not created in the directory I've specified for object files.

General gist of my Makefile:

```
CC = g++-5
CFLAGS = -Wall -c
LFLAGS = -Wall
STD = -std=c++14

all: firsttwenty secondtwenty

firsttwenty: p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 p7 p8 p9 p10 p11 p12 p13 p14 p15 p16 p17 p18 p19 p20
secondtwenty: p21 p22 p23 p24 p25

#
# FIRST TWENTY
#
p1: object_files/problem1.o
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) object_files/problem1.o -o p1 $(STD)

object_files/problem1.o: solutions/problem1.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) solutions/problem1.cpp $(STD)

p2: object_files/problem2.o
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) object_files/problem2.o -o p2 $(STD)

object_files/problem2.o: solutions/problem2.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) solutions/problem2.cpp $(STD)

p3: object_files/problem3.o
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) object_files/problem3.o -o p3 $(STD)

object_files/problem3.o: solutions/problem3.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) solutions/problem3.cpp $(STD)

...
```

It goes on like this for all the solutions.
When I type `make` in the console repeatedly, I would expect this output:

`make: Nothing to be done for 'all'`

However, I'm instead getting this every time:

```
g++-5 -Wall -c solutions/problem15.cpp -std=c++14
g++-5 -Wall -c solutions/problem16.cpp -std=c++14
g++-5 -Wall -c solutions/problem20.cpp -std=c++14
g++-5 -Wall -c solutions/problem22.cpp -std=c++14
g++-5 -Wall -c solutions/problem24.cpp -std=c++14
g++-5 -Wall -c solutions/problem25.cpp -std=c++14
```

Instead of having their object files outputted in `object_files/`,
they are instead placed in the same directory as the makefile.

My directory setup is as follows:

```
project_euler
  |
  |-- downloaded_files
  |     |
  |     |-- p022_names.txt
  |-- headers
  |     |
  |     |-- bigint.h
  |-- object_files
  |     |
  |     |-- problem1.o
  |     |-- problem2.o
  |     |-- ... (other object files)
  |-- solutions
  |     |
  |     |-- problem1.cpp
  |     |-- problem2.cpp
  |     |-- ... (other .cpp files)
  |-- Makefile
  |-- p1
  |-- p2
  |-- p3
  |-- ... (other binary outputs)
```

So I guess I have two questions:

***1)*** Why are these random files recompiling each time/putting their .o files in the root?

***2)*** Is there some way I can compress my Makefile so I don't have to write the same thing time after time for each solution?

Answer (score 4):

The line

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) solutions/problem1.cpp $(STD)
```

does not create the object file `object_files/problem1.o`. Instead, it creates the .o file in the directory from where `make` is run. Change that line to:

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ solutions/problem1.cpp $(STD)
```

Make similar changes in other places too.

---

You can reduce the repetitive parts of the makefile by using a generic rule for the .o files.

```
object_files/%.o: solutions/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(STD) $?
```

You can read more about the automatic variables available in GNU make at https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html.

Comment: This does eliminate the remaking issue, but those 6 seemingly-random object files still are placed in the directory from which `make` is run.

Comment: @IanH, perhaps they are old files or you still have the rules of those specific object files in the old form.

Comment: You were right. I assumed they had been regenerated, but they were, in fact, old files. Thanks! Any ideas on how to consolidate all these repetitive lines into a couple rules?